# Oracle Database query results in "ValueError: year XXXX is out of range" error while fetching data from a datetime column

Tags: python, database, oracle, python-oracledb

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import boto3
import json
import datetime
import oracledb
import os

def DateTimeConverter(value):
    if value.year > 9999:
        return datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
        return value


def OutputHandler(cursor, name, defaulttype, length, precision, scale):
    print("OutputHandler: ", name, defaulttype, length, precision, scale)
    if defaulttype == oracledb.DB_TYPE_DATE:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_DATE, arraysize=cursor.arraysize, outconverter=DateTimeConverter)
    
def connect_to_db(user, password, host, port, service):
    try:
        conn = oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password,
                                dsn=host+":"+port+"/"+service, mode=oracledb.SYSDBA)
        conn.outputtypehandler = OutputHandler
        return conn
    except oracledb.DatabaseError as e:
        print('Error connecting to database: {}\n'.format(e))
        raise e

connection = connect_to_db("", "", "", "5500", "")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("select T$RGDT from T_ERPLNFP3.TBPTMM111100")

data = cursor.fetchall()

print("Row count: ", cursor.rowcount)

print(data[0])

cursor.close()

connection.close()
```

I am trying to fetch data from an Oracle database using Python and the oracledb module. One of the columns in the table has a datetime format and all the values in the column are '4712-01-01 00:00:00.000'. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
`File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 587, in oracledb.thin_impl.Buffer.read_date
File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 359, in oracledb.thin_impl.Buffer.parse_date
File ".eggs/Cython-0.29.33-py3.11-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Includes/cpython/datetime.pxd", line 120, in cpython.datetime.datetime_new
ValueError: year 60824 is out of range`
```

I cannot change the source data, so I need to find a way to fetch the data without making any changes to the database. When I run the same query in DB_Veawer or similar software, I get the output without any issues.

Can someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can fetch the data without any issues using Python and oracledb module? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the columns in the table has a **datetime format**

What does that mean? Which **datatype** is it? I presume it isn't `DATE` nor `TIMESTAMP` but `VARCHAR2`, and values are stored as strings in - what you call - "datetime format"

---

> and **all** the values in the column are '**4712**-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

Apparently, not all, according to

> ValueError: year **60824** is out of range`

---

That value - 60824 - smells like what I previously said, that you stored values as strings because Oracle supports years in range from -4713 to +9999 (without year 0). For example:

```
SQL> select to_date('-5000', 'syyyy') from dual;
select to_date('-5000', 'syyyy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0


SQL>
```

---

You said

> When I run the same query in DB_Veawer or similar software, I get the output without any issues.

Well, are you sure that query you ran returned all rows? GUI tools usually return the first 50 or a few hundreds of rows, which means that - if invalid values are stored *out of the initial reach*, query won't fail.

---

If column contains invalid values, you'll have to first find them, and then decide what you want to do with them. I don't know Python so I can't suggest anything; if it were SQL, I'd probably use `SUBSTR` function in `CASE` expression. For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '60824-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select '4712-01-01'  from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    case when substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-') - 1) not between -4713 and 9999 then date '4712-01-01'
  7         else to_date(col, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  8    end result
  9  from test;

COL         RESULT
----------- ----------
60824-01-01 01.01.4712    --> invalid year value set to 4712
4712-01-01  01.01.4712    --> valid

SQL>
```

Maybe you can implement something like that in Python; can't tell.

Certainly, it just depends on what new *garbage* will you find in that column. As it stores strings, nothing prevents it from values like '12cF-0x-3$' which kind of follows "yyyy-mm-dd" format, but that isn't a valid date value.

---

From my point of view, that seems to be yet another example of problems people have when they store date values into inappropriate datatype columns.

Comment: It seems this issue is same like the issue mentioned in here. https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/166

Comment: However the year 60824 is comes as 65536 - 4712 as explained in the above article